# How to integrate a git submodule to a git workflow

Tags: git, git-submodules, weblate

Here's my situation : my team and I have a project using a front end framework. It works great and is correctly organized with a typical git workflow with `master`, `develop` and `features/fixes` branches.

We now have an increasing need to add a large number of translations to our project (translations are located in a single folder). We decided to try out Weblate to manage them. Right now, Weblate has a full access to our entire git repository to push translations.

For security reasons, we want `Weblate` to only have access to our translation folder. We thought we could create a git submodule for the translation and give `weblate` an access to it.

Unfortunately, I am not sure of how we could easily integrate a submodule to our current workflow.

I thought of a solution but I am not sure it is possible : I want to create a submodule with a workflow similar to the main project. When a developer (or weblate) wants to update a translation, he has to create a feature branch on both the main project and the submodule and then merge both branch when the feature is finished.

I am not familiar with git submodules and there is probably a smarter way to do this so your thoughts on this would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to reference in your main project the translation folder/submodule, set to [follow the latest commit from its `main` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

That means at any point in your main repository, a [`git submodule update --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---remote) will update the submodule to its latest commit.

That way, you can have a pull-request/merge policy within your separate `translation` repository, and, once reviewed and merged in its main branch, a `submodule update --remote` in the main repository will get the latest revision of that submodule.